# Define static method as returning instance of current class

Tags: typescript

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
class Base {
   static foo(): <???>; // <= What goes here?
}

class Subclass extends Base {}

Subclass.foo() // <= I want this to have a return type of Subclass, not Base
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript has been adding features aggressively over the past year, including support for [using class types in generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics). [This example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Constructor%3CM%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20M%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20foo%3CT%20extends%20Base%3E(this%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this()%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Subclass%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20bar%20%3D%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASubclass.foo().bar%0D%0A) compiles in 2.3 or later:

```js
interface Constructor<M> {
  new (...args: any[]): M
}

class Base {
  static foo<T extends Base>(this: Constructor<T>): T {
    return new this()
  }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  readonly bar = 1
}

// Prove we have a Subclass instance by invoking a subclass-specific method:
Subclass.foo().bar
```

Comment: This is really useful. They should document it more clearly.

Comment: But doing it this way ignore the benefit of type check

Comment: @Singgum3b this solution is typesafe afaict. Are you using a recent TypeScript (like, from this year)?

Comment: `...args: any[]` is this not skipping type checking of any subsequent class constructor ?

Comment: Ah, yes, correct. The `...args: any[]` is just an example. If you need typesafety for the constructor, certainly you should modify Constructor to match your class' constructor signature.

Comment: But you can't reference other static properties from within `foo` - which suuuucks: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=18&ssc=15&pln=17&pc=19#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxQK4JjpQA8AsgHzIDeAsAFDLIgQDuyAFAHQ9xQDmWAFzI4IAJ4BtALoBKEWQYBfBgwQAbOFizIAQlpR1GyHHDDAEJ9AFsIABSjoADsgC8yAORYbEAGpx1PAgPAG4GJlNzSxh0dBIAFWQIAA9IEAATHX0sCAoOMAALYGE0TBx8QmIEilkacKZkBDKwZCdHF3dC4q5vWwdnMOMmKAgwPCgQZjZkLqwOWXqVeiW1TW1kAGU8ACMNLR0UtMy9AzrjEbh0zHVxZG2+N2QARmVVei3dtawuGPR5rnuUAYQA

Comment: @RyanWheale I found a solution using InstanceType<T>, though you have to type the return of new this(). https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoa0IBcw4EthsB7AWwQAUAnEgB2gF5oByCchANTBAFcEWAbgxZc+ItABmJEgB4AKtAQAPHAgB2AExg4AnnQQlJcRAD4AFDgAWBCAC5o8gJQOAkurHrgCefoQLTFBEsaGASDxxoOloGZmtbADp2Chp6YUwQ6gQcXmp1aHUEAHdoeIhzJ2hIaHdPb18DAPSsAF8MNvQMUEgYAGVeACNuqCVVDW0TCCQ0DKywTXCQXWgBsGomaABGdowMfqHwKATpEgqE1eoMIA

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you need to annotate explicitly or write in a way that the compiler can infer it:

```
class Base {
   static foo() {
       return new Base();
   } 
}

class Subclass extends Base {
    static foo() {
       return new Subclass();
    }
}

Subclass.foo()
```

In either case `Subclass` needs to have *some* form of duplicated definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with casting `new this`, you can use [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype). This allows you to use static properties on `Base`

```js
class Base {
  static someProp = 'someValue';
  static foo<T extends typeof Base>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    const prop = this.someProp;
    return new this() as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}

class Subclass extends Base {
  readonly bar = 1
}

Subclass.foo().bar
```